# Specify orientations on Swift Playgrounds app?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground

I need to lock a Swift Playgrounds app to a specific orientation, but am having difficulties due to the lack of an `Info.plist`. Playgrounds apps are not compatible with plist files, making any sort of property edits as you would in a normal Xcode project impossible.

All programmatic solutions require the plist property `Requires Full Screen` to be enabled, which of course isn't available in this environment. Editing `Package.swift` works temporarily, however will be rewritten after an unpredictable amount of time, or after being run on another device.

How can I achieve an orientation lock with these restrictions in mind?